# How to catch PSQLException value too long for type character varying

Tags: spring, hibernate, postgresql, plpgsql

I'm currently testing the data access layer that I've created in spring (PersistenceContext is injected). So I have a stateless EJB that calls a service for example UserService, that inserts/delete/update data in the database.

The service works fine, I was able to insert database. But when I was testing and I input string value that is longer than the set length I got:

```
javax.transaction.RollbackException: Transaction marked for rollback.
WARNING: DTX5014: Caught exception in beforeCompletion() callback:
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.DataException: ERROR: value too long for type character varying(20)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.DataException: ERROR: value too long for type character varying(20)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.DataException: ERROR: value too long for type character varying(20)
```

My partial code:

```
@PersistenceContext
protected EntityManager entityManager;

try {
    entityManager.persist(e);
} catch(Exception e) {
  //log message here
}
```

Then I've tried everything to catch these errors but I was not able to. Any suggestion on how to resolve the issue?

Thanks,

czetsuya

Comment: *I wasn't able to* is not an error message I have seen before. What exactly did not work. Show us the code where you tried to catch the error and explain why you "*weren't able" to catch it.

Comment: The code is right there: entityManager.persist(e), the problem is I am inserting a value that is too long for the field for example name(5), then I insert namenamename. Even if I enclosed persist() method with try/catch, it wasn't able to catch the error.

Comment: I still don't see any try/catch in your code. And you still didn't explain why you cannot catch it.

Comment: I've added the try catch block. It simply wraps the persists method.

Comment: I'm just simply invoking the persist method of the entityManager which works when the parameters are correct, but when value is too long for the datafield it throws and error as expected. But the problem is I wasn't able to catch it in code. Perhaps the commit is invoke by the container late.

Comment: Hi, have you found any solution? I cannot catch it and cannot control the application flow if this happens.

Answer (score 1):

I've used the following code to find out which error is thrown under your circumstances:

```
BEGIN;
CREATE TABLE t(v varchar(5));
DO $body$
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO t VALUES ('1234567');
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
  RAISE NOTICE '!!! %, %', SQLSTATE, SQLERRM;
END;$body$;
ROLLBACK;
```

You'll see, that error code is `22001`, error is named `string_data_right_truncation` per [PostrgeSQL's list of error codes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/errcodes-appendix.html).

I don't know how to catch this error in the Hibernate, but on the [PL/pgSQL level](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-ERROR-TRAPPING) you can do it using:

```sql
EXCEPTION WHEN SQLSTATE '22001' THEN
    -- your code follows
END;
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, hmm but I can't really use this since the error happens on the code not on stored procedure :-?

Comment: In the first code block I've wrapped the `INSERT` statement into the anonymous code block. Yes, such handling is only possible in stored procedures. But maybe you can use `SQLSTATE` in the Hibernate too?..